# Drill query taking large time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache-drill

I am running the drill query using node.js.It is taking more than 500ms for retrieving only 10 records.I am using http request method of nodejs.

```
function executeService(params) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    try {
        var serverOptions = {
            hostname: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8047,
            path: "/query.json",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        };
        var http = require("http");
        var req = http.request(serverOptions, function (res) {
            if (params && params.response) {
                res.setEncoding('binary');
            } else {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
            }
            var body = '';
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                resolve(body);

            });
        });
        req.on('error', function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });
        req.write(params);
        req.end();
    } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
  })
}

var params = '{"query": "select * from mongo.school.student limit 10", "queryType": "SQL"}';

executeService(params).then(function (res) {
  console.log("res>>>>>>>>>>>" + res);
 })
```

Is it right way of running drill query from nodejs?if yes how can i decrease the query time?

Comment: How long does the query take without using node.js?

Comment: In terminal this same query is taking 150ms. while mongo takes only 30-40ms

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not much you can do about this on your end. If this is still an issue for you get in touch with the Drill team on the mailing lists https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/ so that they can create a ticket and work on improving it.